# MYSQL GROUP BY - slow query

Tags: mysql

I have a query like below, please help to give proper index for this, the contact table have more than 20K records and it take nearly 20 secs to load.
Hope the group by clause makes the problem, if I remove the group by clause total record is more than 300k.

```
SELECT `a`.*, CONCAT(a.`firstname`, " ", a.`lastname`) AS `cont_name`, CONCAT(a.`position`, " / ", a.`company`) AS `comp_pos`, `e`.`name` AS `industry_name`, CONCAT(f.`firstname`, " ", f.`lastname`) AS `created_by` 
FROM `contacts` AS `a` 
LEFT JOIN `user_centres` AS `b` ON a.user_id = b.user_id 
LEFT JOIN `group_contacts` AS `c` ON a.id = c.contact_id 
LEFT JOIN `groups` AS `d` ON c.group_id = d.id 
LEFT JOIN `industries` AS `e` ON e.id = a.industry_id 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `f` ON f.id = a.user_id 
WHERE (1) 
GROUP BY `a`.`id` 
ORDER BY `a`.`created` desc
```

Explain shows like this - 20145 Using temporary; Using filesort

Comment: Remove the `group by`.  You have no aggregation functions, so it doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: Can you post the full explain and the table layouts? Are the LEFT OUTER JOINs necessary, or can you just use INNER JOINs?

Comment: LEFT JOIN `group_contacts` AS `c` ON a.id = c.contact_id 
LEFT JOIN `groups` AS `d` ON c.group_id = d.id are unnecessary joins... remove it

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - GROUP BY slow down the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454440/mysql-group-by-slow-down-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps

1. There is no use of table group ( d ), so you can remove left join to group from this query
2. Add index for `user_id`, `contact_id` and `industry_id` ( I hope these ids are joining table primary_keys ) in contacts table
3. check these ids `user_id`, `contact_id` and `industry_id` types ( INT ) are same.