# MySQL - GROUP BY slow down the page

Tags: php, mysql

GROUP BY clause in the query below slow down the page, please help to resolve this issue

```
 SELECT 
    `a`.*, 
    CONCAT(a.`firstname`, " ", a.`lastname`) AS `cont_name`,
    CONCAT(a.`position`, " / ", a.`company`) AS `comp_pos`,
    CONCAT(f.`firstname`, " ", f.`lastname`) AS `created_by` 
FROM 
    `contacts` AS `a`
    LEFT JOIN `users` AS `f` ON f.id = a.user_id
    LEFT JOIN `user_centres` AS `b` ON a.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE b.centre_id IN (23, 24, 25, 26, 20, 21, 22, 27, 28)
GROUP BY `a`.`id` 
ORDER BY `a`.`created` desc
```

Here the join with `user_centres` table is for centre wise filtering of data. `EXPLAIN` gives the result as:

```
- 1 SIMPLE a index PRIMARY,user_id,area_id,industry_id,country PRIMARY 4 NULL 20145 Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Our requirement is as below

1. Listing of all contacts in admin login
2. Centre wise listing of contacts in manager/clerk login

Total records in contact table is > 20K.

There will be multiple entry for users in `user_centres` table, ie: a user is assigned to more than one centre.

While executing the query in server by excluding `GROUP BY` is nearly 300k data which makes the problem.

**Db stucture**

Table structure for table `contacts`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contacts` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`imported` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`situation` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`firstname` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
`lastname` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
`position` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
`dob` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`office_contact` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`mobile_contact` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`company` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
`industry_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`city` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
`country` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`isclient` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`classification` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`created` datetime NOT NULL,
`updated` datetime NOT NULL,
`unsubscribe` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25203 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Indexes for table `contacts`

```
ALTER TABLE `contacts`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
ADD KEY `industry_id` (`industry_id`), ADD KEY `country` (`country`);
```

Constraints for table `contacts`

```
ALTER TABLE `contacts`
ADD CONSTRAINT `contacts_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) 
REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `contacts_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`industry_id`) 
REFERENCES `industries` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `contacts_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`country`) 
REFERENCES `country` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Table structure for table `users`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`salt` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`status_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
`firstname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`lastname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Indexes for table `users`

```
ALTER TABLE `users`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`),
ADD KEY `type_id_idx` (`role_id`), ADD KEY `status_id_idx` (`status_id`);
```

Constraints for table `users`

```
ALTER TABLE `users`
ADD CONSTRAINT `role_id` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) 
REFERENCES `users_roles` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `status_id` FOREIGN KEY (`status_id`) 
REFERENCES `users_status` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`area`) 
REFERENCES `area` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Table structure for table `user_centres`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_centres` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`area_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`centre_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=72 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Indexes for table `user_centres`

```
ALTER TABLE `user_centres`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
ADD KEY `centre_id` (`centre_id`), ADD KEY `area_id` (`area_id`);
```

Constraints for table `user_centres`

```
ALTER TABLE `user_centres`
ADD CONSTRAINT `user_centres_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) 
REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `user_centres_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`centre_id`) 
REFERENCES `centre` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Also please refer EXPLAIN screens - http://prntscr.com/6o5h8s

Comment: You are misusing the nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY` and you may well be misusing `GROUP BY` itself. Please read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html   Question: what's the relationship between your `contacts` and your `users` tables? Is it 1:1?

Answer (score 0):

Index were not used because of the different ORDER BY a GROUP BY clauses.

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html
```

Comment: Hi Manadh,
Thanks for your quick response, how can I implement sorting here. Here the sorting comes with dynamic field on clicking the field heading in contact listing.

Answer (score 0):

You are spending a lot of time checking `user_centres`, but not needing anything from it.  Remove it from the query.

`users` can be made into a correlates subquery:

```
SELECT  `a`.*,
        CONCAT(a.`firstname`, " ", a.`lastname`) AS `cont_name`,
        CONCAT(a.`position`, " / ", a.`company`) AS `comp_pos`,
        ( SELECT  CONCAT(f.`firstname`, " ", f.`lastname`)
            FROM  `users` AS `f` ON f.id = a.user_id 
        ) AS `created_by`
    FROM  `contacts` AS `a`
    GROUP BY  `a`.`id`
    ORDER BY  `a`.`created` desc
```

Do you really need all 20K rows??  The sheer bulk of the result is part of the sluggishness.

Comment: looks to me like he wants to filter the result set based on a column in `user_centres`.

Comment: But with a `LEFT JOIN`, it does not matter whether there is a match or not.

Comment: Yes Jones, I need to filter the result set based on a column in user_centres. this is the condition WHERE b.centre_id IN (23, 24, 25, 26, 20, 21, 22, 27, 28)

Comment: Then don't use `LEFT` when `JOIN`ing to `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, based on the feedback got from all of you I have tried the query below now and give me the speed improvement from 30 secs to 15 secs

```
SELECT  `a`.`id`, `a`.`user_id`, `a`.`imported`, `a`.`created`,
        `a`.`unsubscribe`, CONCAT(a.firstname, " ", a.lastname) AS `cont_name`,
        CONCAT(a.position, " / ", a.company) AS `comp_pos`, 
      ( SELECT  COUNT(uc.id)
            FROM  `user_centres` AS `uc`
            WHERE  (uc.user_id = a.user_id)
              AND  (uc.centre_id IN (29))
            GROUP BY  `uc`.`user_id`
      ) AS `centre_cnt`, 
      ( SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.group_name
                    ORDER BY  g.group_name ASC SEPARATOR ", ")
            FROM  `groups` AS `g`
            INNER JOIN  `group_contacts` AS `gc` ON g.id = gc.group_id
            WHERE  (gc.contact_id = a.id)
            GROUP BY  `gc`.`contact_id`
      ) AS `group_name`, 
      ( SELECT  CONCAT(u.`firstname`, " ", u.`lastname`)
            FROM  `users` AS `u`
            WHERE  (u.id = a.user_id)
      ) AS `created_by`, `e`.`name` AS `industry_name`
    FROM  `contacts` AS `a`
    LEFT JOIN  `industries` AS `e` ON e.id = a.industry_id
    WHERE  (1)
    HAVING  (centre_cnt is NOT NULL)
    ORDER BY  `a`.`id` desc
```

Let me know Is there a way to improve the speed and make the page loading below 5 secs.

Please see the interface (noted the filtering and sorting fields) - http://prntscr.com/6q6q70

Comment: Now change `COUNT(uc.id)` to `COUNT(*)` and add the compound index `INDEX(user_id, centre_id)` on `user_centres`.  These changes should switch it to "Using index", which is faster.